# Difference among key volumeAvailableCapacityKey, volumeAvailableCapacityForImportantUsageKey and volumeAvailableCapacityForOpportunisticUsageKey

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to get the free disk space before downloading some file to my app. In `iOS 11` I'm doing this as follow

```
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)

        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            // Running iOS 11 OR NEWER
            let pathURL = URL(fileURLWithPath:paths.last!)
            do {
                let values = try pathURL.resourceValues(forKeys: [.volumeAvailableCapacityKey])
                if let capacity = values.volumeAvailableCapacityForImportantUsage {
                    return capacity;
                } else {
                    return nil;
                }
            } catch {
                return nil
            }
        }
```

Now my question is-

what is the difference among `volumeAvailableCapacityKey`, `volumeAvailableCapacityForImportantUsageKey` and `volumeAvailableCapacityForOpportunisticUsageKey` and what I should use to get the actual space available in the device?

Comment: I assume  that you read *"Decide Which Query Type to Use"* and the documentation of those keys  at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlresourcekey/checking_volume_storage_capacity ?

Comment: @MartinR but the documentation doesn't have much details. when to use what?

Answer (score 2):

As per Apple docs :

> **volumeAvailableCapacityKey**
>   Key for the volume’s available capacity in bytes (read-only)
>
> **volumeAvailableCapacityForImportantUsageKey**
>   Key for the volume’s available capacity in bytes for storing important
>   resources (read-only)
>
> **volumeAvailableCapacityForOpportunisticUsageKey** 
>   Key for the volume’s available capacity in bytes for storing nonessential resources (read-only)
>
> **volumeTotalCapacityKey**
>   Key for the volume’s total capacity in bytes
>   (read-only)

I would suggest you to read this [**Apple doc**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlresourcekey/checking_volume_storage_capacity) very carefully. It highlights :

> #### Overview
>
> Before you try to store a large amount of data locally, first verify that you have sufficient storage capacity. To get the storage capacity of a volume, you construct a URL (using an instance of URL) that references an object on the volume to be queried, and then query that volume.
>
> #### Decide Which Query Type to Use
>
> The query type to use depends on what's being stored. If you’re storing data based on a user request or resources the app requires to function properly (for example, a video the user is about to watch or resources that are needed for the next level in a game), query against `volumeAvailableCapacityForImportantUsageKey`. However, if you’re downloading data in a more predictive manner (for example, downloading a newly available episode of a TV series that the user has been watching recently), query against `volumeAvailableCapacityForOpportunisticUsageKey`.

And a very interesting example indeed :

```
let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath:"/")
do {
    let values = try fileURL.resourceValues(forKeys: [.volumeAvailableCapacityForImportantUsageKey])
    if let capacity = values.volumeAvailableCapacityForImportantUsage {
        print("Available capacity for important usage: \(capacity)")
    } else {
        print("Capacity is unavailable")
    }
} catch {
    print("Error retrieving capacity: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Comment: I have gone through the Apple docs but description to those keys are very brief and doesn't clarify when to use what?